# Retrieve azure blob storage connection string from airflow connection id

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-storage, connection-string

I am trying to see how can I retrieve the azure connection string value stored in airflow as a connection ID.

I have called the azure blob storage connection id using `azure_conn` as shown below. I am trying to see how can I return back the connection string from this variable `azure_conn`

```
azure_conn = WasbHook(wasb_conn_id='wasb_conn_id')
```

The variable azure_conn is of type

```
<class 'airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.hooks.wasb.WasbHook'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WasbHook` has access to a `get_connection()` method inherited from the `BaseHook` (see [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f8ba4755ae77f3e08275d18e5df13c368363066b/airflow/hooks/base.py#L59)).  You can instantiate the `WasbHook` as you do now and then call the `get_connection()` method to retrieve attributes from the Azure Blob Storage Connection you setup.

```py
hook = WasbHook(wasb_conn_id='wasb_conn_id')
conn = hook.get_connection(hook.conn_id)
print(conn.extra_dejson) # To retrieve the connection string
```